# ngStyle AngularJs put variable attribute

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, uikit, progress-bar

I need create a progressbar using uikit. According to uikit this is how it works:

```
<div class="uk-progress">
    <div class="uk-progress-bar" style="width: 40%;">40%</div>
</div>
```

Of course this is a static method. So i have created a function that calculates the percentage in angular:

```
getPercentage: function() {
                var self = this;
                var done = this.downloadStatus.done.replace(/,/g, "");
                var total = this.downloadStatus.total.replace(/,/g, "");
                self.percentage = 0;
                if (parseInt(total) != 0) {
                    self.percentage = (parseInt(done) / parseInt(total)) * 100;
                }
                return self.percentage;
            }
```

The "style" of the bar determinates its width in the html.. is it possible using ng-style of angular to have a dynamic width? I tried with:

```
<div class="uk-progress">
        <div class="uk-progress-bar" ng-style="{{getPercentage()}}">40%</div>
    </div>
```

but not works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="uk-progress-bar" ng-style="getPercentage()">40%</div>
```

ngStyle is supposed do be dynamic, its attribute is an expression (you may need to put it into single quotes to make it static string). Otherwise style would be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

`ngStyle` didn't need `{{}}`.

You can have a try:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('testController', function($scope) {
    $scope.test={color: "red"}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    
    <div ng-style="test">{{test}}</div>        
    <input type="text" ng-model="test.color"/>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about saving the dynamic style on the scope

```
$scope.progressBarWidth = getPercentage();
```

and update it along side the download progress or whatever triggers the progress bar to move, and surround that in an `$asyncEval`

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function() {
   $scope.progressBarWidth = getPercentage();
});
```

This way it will update the progress bar. 
Your HTML will look like so

```
<div class="uk-progress-bar" ng-style="progressBarWidth">40%</div>
```

Comment: in this way i have: $scope.$asyncEval is not a function.. many javascript errors

Comment: Sorry, try with `$scope.$evalAsync` I always mix that one up

Comment: not works.. this is what now i have done and seems works:  <div class="uk-progress-bar" data-ng-style="{'width': documents.percentage+'%'}"> .. First time it works but if i do the same operation anothe once more the progress bar starts from 100% and go back to 60% (for example)...it's strange

Comment: hmm, wired, if you want you can paste your code into a http://jsfiddle.net/ and I can take a look